# @Html.ActionLink with the item Name as a link

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, actionlink

I'm having a hard time on a thing that in the end, must be simple.
Using a @Html.ActionLink , all I want is a link with the text of the name from the Model on a table.

Here's what I'm doing:

```
<td data-th="Nome">@Html.ActionLink( @item.Name , "Details", new { id = @item.UserID })</td>
```

But I get the error:

> HtmlHelper has not applicable method named 'ActionLink' but
>   appears to have an extension method by that name. Extension methods
>   cannot be dynamically dispatched. Consider casting the dynamic
>   arguments or calling the extension method without the extension method
>   syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem happens when you try to pass dynamic varibles inside extensions methods. This is not supported.

Problably you have one of these situations:

1. Your `Name` property is a dynamic varible. You can try casting it to `string`: `(string) @item.Name`
2. You forgot to add your Model at the top of your View: `@model MyModel`.

Comment: I do not know if it has to do , but it was like String and threw the value to a variable string , and it worked. Thank you, did not know that was going to give this problem String scheme to string

Answer (score 0):

For MVC 3+ version

```
@Html.ActionLink( @item.Name , "Action_Name", "Controller_Name" , new { id = @item.UserID }, null)
```

### OR

```
@Html.ActionLink( @item.Name , "Action_Name", "Controller_Name" , new { @item.UserID }, null)
```

ID is no longer require in mvc 3+ versions